# How to read object of Session ASP.net in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, session

I have a session in ASP, it's object. Now, I want read some value of object in client , I known Session live in Server , at client only read it.

[image]

```
 var obj = UserModBus.Login(user_name, pass_word);
        if (obj != null)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session["OBJ"] = obj;
        }
```

In my page using javascript

```
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function () {        
var full_name = '((QLNT.DATA.USER_MOD) Session["OBJ"]).FULL_NAME%>';
var birth_day = '((QLNT.DATA.USER_MOD) Session["OBJ"]).BIRTH_DAY%>';
        window.onload = function () {
            alert(full_name + birth_day);
        }
    });
</script>
```

But it's not working. Can you give me some advice to solve it?

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it because you are missing the <%=?

```
...
var full_name = '<%=((QLNT.DATA.USER_MOD) Session["OBJ"]).FULL_NAME%>';
var birth_day = '<%=((QLNT.DATA.USER_MOD) Session["OBJ"]).BIRTH_DAY%>';
...
```